# Textarea форматирование данных

Tags: xhtml, html, html5, php

Уважамые люди помогите разобратся с textarea в html. Мне нужно выводить в него некую информацию, я етим проблем нет но она отображаеться некоректно!! Нужно что бы данные отображались в виде таблицы но если одно имя больше другова тогда вся строка слезает на несколько пробелов и колонки не совпадают со значениями!!
Правильный

1.**Василий***_******Пупкин***** **_**_1 место

2.**Ян***_******_***_Лу***_***** **_**2 место

3.__Иван***_******___Русланов-Бе лый***3 место

Подскажите как поймать количество табов? И вообще можно ли форматировать текст в textarea??

Answer (score 1):

Ну как бы JS'ом это все делается, который каждое нажатие на клавиши в textarea будет вызывать данную проверку, которая будет все необходимое вам подгонять, а чтобы поймать кол-во, данную систему берите в некоторые обозначители типа: `[settab][/settab]` тогда скрипт будет знать, в какой области ему работать и будет корректно.

Comment: Спасибо!  А есть какой то пример такого JS?